# How to return specific values from a table

Tags: sql, oracle, join, subquery

I need to return rows from a table where all of the rows for an `ID` have some specific value for `CODE`.

For example:

```
TABLE: A

ID   | NAME  |CODE
-----------------
101  | XXX   | A
101  | XXX   | B
101  | XXX   | C
101  | XXX   | A
102  | XXX   | B
103  | XXX   | B
104  | XXX   | D
104  | XXX   | B
105  | XXX   | A
105  | XXX   | B
105  | XXX   | D
105  | XXX   | A
106  | XXX   | B
107  | XXX   | B
```

I need the rows which have only code `B`. So here is the expected output from the above table:

```
ID   | NAME  |CODE
-----------------
102  | XXX   | B
103  | XXX   | B
106  | XXX   | B
107  | XXX   | B
```

**Here `ID` 101, 104, 105 also has code B, but they should not return in my output as they have another codes also.**

What query can I write to get above the output?

I also need to make sure these values do not exist in another table B. So, I need to add

```
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE B WHERE B.ID = A.ID)
```

B table has Primary key `ID` and there is no Code column in B table. I am just using this table to eliminate the common IDs because I need the results which exists in Table A and not Table B.

Here is the Example data in

```
Table : B 

ID  | Name  | City  | Department
------------------------------
101  | XXX   | XXX  | XX
104  | XXX   | XXX  | XX
105  | XXX   | XXX  | XX
107  | XXX   | XXX  | XX
```

in Table A , 107 `ID` is having only B in `Code` column. However, it exists in Table B so I don't want to return this row in my output.

Comment: Hi, None of the below answers solve my problem, Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method:

```
select b.id
from tableb b
group by b.id
having min(b.code) = max(b.code) and min(b.code) = 'B';
```

If you specifically mean no "A" and "B", but other codes are allowed, then you can do:

```
select b.id
from tableb b
where b.code in ('A', 'B')
group by b.id
having min(b.code) = max(b.code) and min(b.code) = 'B';
```

Comment: Sorry, if my question was not clear, the second table has no Code column. I am using that for only eliminate the common IDs because i need to get the IDs which are existing in only table A.

Comment: @signup . . . There is no *second* table as I read the question:  "I need to return values from a table which has some specific code. This table has no primary key column.".

Comment: I've edited the question - hope it's clearer and still what @signup meant.

Comment: @Gordon-Linoff      Can you please take a look now?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson TQ:)

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option:

```
select id
from tableb
group by id
having sum(decode(code, 'B', 0, 1)) = 0
```

**[EDITED after the question was modified]**

```
select *
from tablea a
where a.id in (select a1.id
               from tablea a1
               group by a1.id
               having sum(decode(a1.code, 'b', 0, 1)) = 0
              )              
  and not exists (select null from tableb b where b.id = a.id)
```

Comment: Question was edited now, Can you please suggest new answer?

Comment: Sure; here you are, have a look, @signup.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, ID 101 is also having code B, above code will consider this? or not? If not can you plz explain how it is working?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT
    ID
    ,NAME
    ,CODE
FROM tblA a
WHERE CODE = 'B'
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT ID
    FROM tblA b
    WHERE CODE <> 'B'
    AND a.ID = b.ID
)
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT ID
    FROM tblB c
    WHERE a.ID = c.ID 
)
```

Comment: Question was edited now, Can you please suggest new answer?

Comment: You should be a little more specific and put some sample data for Table B as well

Comment: Hi @Valerica, Now i modified question can you please take a look?

Comment: @signup Done, I have changed the query.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you need grouping function like `count` and you want to preserve all details use analytical function. Oracle says:

> They differ from aggregate functions in that they return multiple rows
>   for each group.

This way you avoid hitting table twice. Also be careful to handle `nulls` properly.

```
select id, name 
  from (select id, name, code, 
               count(case when code <> 'B' or code is null then 1 end) 
                     over (partition by id) cnt
          from a) a
  where cnt = 0 and not exists (select 1 from b where id = a.id)
```

**<sup>[SQL demo](http://rextester.com/BISAH25304)</sup>**

Comment: Hi @Ponder-Stibbons, Can you please change code with using " * " in select statement ?